# How do I make rvm find a global binary when inside a project with a Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, gemfile, global-scope

I am using rvm and ruby 2.1.0 in a project.

```
$~/ rvm version
rvm 1.25.33 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$~/ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

I want to use the [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem in that project, but I don't want to have that gem in the project's gemfile. So I installed it globally, and I can use it outside of my project:

```
$~/ gem install dotenv
$~/ touch .env
$~/ dotenv echo "works"
works
```

The problem is that once I enter my project (or any folder with a Gemfile) rubygems says that `dotenv` "can not be found":

```
$~/ cd my-project
$my-project/ touch .env
$my-project/ dotenv echo "can not find dotenv"
/Users/kikito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'dotenv' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
   from /Users/kikito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
   ...
```

When I remove the Gemfile, `dotenv` works again:

```
$my-project/ rm Gemfile
$my-project/ dotenv echo "dotenv works again as soon as I remove the Gemfile"
dotenv works again as soon as I remove the Gemfile
```

I am using zsh on a mac. My .zshrc seems to be ok (rvm does not complaint about unconfigured paths or anything)

```
# ~/.zshrc
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
...
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOBIN # Add golang binaries
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin # Add node binaries path
PATH=$PATH:/usr/X11/bin # Add xquartz to path, so xvfb is detected
...
# RVM
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Here's the [output of `rvm info`](https://gist.github.com/kikito/5344a1d5c82bed0e9bf8) in case it helps. It's the same output from inside and outside of `my-project`.

Is this a regular rvm thing, or do I have some missconfiguration? Can I make this work, or do I have to put dotenv on the Gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to [`rubygems-bundler`](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler), which RVM installs by default. Try running

```
$ NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 dotenv echo "whatever"
```

If that works, you could do `export NOEXEC_EXCLUDE="dotenv"` to stop `dotenv` from sing Bundler all the time.